# “Percent” in chart title and on axis – redundant?

Tags: writing-style, graphics

Consider the chart below:

[image: Example Cchart]

When writing *percent* in the title, and *%* on the axis marks, is this redundant? Is the word *amount* preferable?

I haven’t seen this addressed in any style guides such as the [APA guidelines](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/20/).

Comment: Please avoid writing "percentage" in the title, just report the quantity that it's represented. For instance, in the example you linked, a more appropriate title would be: "Fraction of the widgets that are blue".

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: That looks like it can be extended to an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input/answer. I did consider "Fraction," but found it equally odd saying "fraction" then reporting percentages. Still, I'm definitely considering your input!

Also, thank you Wrzlprmft for the formatting edits. (And the typing tutor that is your username.)

Answer (score 8):

*Percentage* (parts per hundred) and, more broadly, abbreviations like *ppm* (parts per million) or *ppb* (parts per billion) do not describe any quantity, they are just multipliers for dimensionless quantities.

In a graph, instead, you should accurately describe the quantity being represented. In the example given in your question, a more appropriate title would probably be: "Fraction of the widgets that are blue".

In the [SI brochure, §5.3.7](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3-7.html), the document that defines the *International System of Units*, it is stated that

> In mathematical expressions, the internationally recognized symbol % (percent) may be used with the SI to represent the number 0.01. Thus, it can be used to express the values of dimensionless quantities.

and, furthermore,

> Phrases such as "percentage by mass", "percentage by volume", or "percentage by amount of substance" should not be used; the extra information on the quantity should instead be conveyed in the name and symbol for the quantity.

The percent symbol can, instead, appear in the tick labels.

Answer (score -3):

At least in physics, usually graphs do not have a title at all.

Comment: True, in most forms of academia you can expect something along the lines of "Figure 2: percent of widgets that are blue".